# How to remove words "Video" from a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I use ffmpeg to make a movie with 100 images *.png, but in the produced movie video.mov, there's big word `VIDEO.mov` at the bottom of my movie and it covers some of my info within the images, how can I remove it?

Comment: Are you sure, that this text isn't introduced by your media player?

Comment: I use VLC, and yes you're right, I just installed another player and the subtitle was gone. I found it would disappear after 5s but my movie is only 4s. Thank you very much for reminding. I'm not quite familiar with linux OS and I should pay more attention to that.

Answer (score 2):

VLC player will display the name of the current playing file for about 5 seconds at the bottom of the video, on top of your own figures, then it will disappear. Since my own one lasts for only 4s then it's "always" there even though I set `repeat` on ;).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CharlieRB I think the answer is just fine (although describing how to change the OSD behavior in VLC would be nice), and the author and answerer are the same.

Comment: Someone told me I could answer my own question if I found one. But he deleted that comment I think. Additionally, I'm sorry, as I have mentioned, I don't know VLC very well, so I just suggest to change to another video player. I chose the first one listed in `Ubuntu` App store.